# node_module_version error on node-v17.6.0

Tags: node.js, electron, node-modules, electron-forge, node-canvas

I can't run node-canvas on electron. says the following issues.

NODE_MODULE_VERSION 102. This version of Node.js requires

NODE_MODULE_VERSION 101. Please try re-compiling or re-installing

`npm version:`
$ npm -v 
8.5.1

`node version:`
$ node -v

17.6.0

`Dependencies:`
[Dependencies Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HI3Tv.png)

```
D:\test-app-latest/node_modules/sha1
Error occurred in handler for 'start-generate': Error: The module '\\?\D:\test-app-latest\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 102. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 101. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
    at process.func [as dlopen] (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:1800)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1199:18)
    at Object.func [as .node] (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:1800)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:829:12)
    at Function.c._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:13331)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1012:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\test-app-latest\node_modules\canvas\lib\bindings.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1116:14) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}
```

Comment: Did you try the solution referenced in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72553650/how-to-get-node-sqlite3-working-on-mac-m1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72553650/how-to-get-node-sqlite3-working-on-mac-m1)